# Insert only time in sql table from c#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, datetime

I have a windows application where i have used date time pickers for shift start and shift end. I have to insert those timings into table. my Code is :

```
if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 0 || comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 1 || comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 2 || comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 3 || comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 4 || comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 5 || comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 6 || comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 7 || comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 8 || comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 9 || comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 10 || comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 11 || comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 12 || comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 13 || comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 14 || comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 15 || comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 16)
{
    string Query = " Insert into [ICPS].[dbo].[Cau reports]( [Name],[Date],[Shift Start],[Shift END ],[Overtime Start],[Overtime End],[Tasks Carried Out],[Normal ],[Overtime],[Normal 1],[Overtime1],[Comments],[Targets_(per hour)]) values ('" + this.textBox1.Text + "','" + this.Date.Text + "', CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),'" + this.SS.Text + "',108), '" + this.SE.Text + "','" + this.OS.Text + "','" + this.OE.Text + "','" + this.comboBox1.SelectedText + "','" + this.NT.Text + "','" + this.OT.Text + "','" + this.textBox2.Text + "','" + this.textBox3.Text + "','" + this.textBox4.Text + "','" + this.textBox5.Text + "' ) ;";

    // string Query = " update [ICPS].[dbo].[Cau reports] set  [Normal]='" + this.textBox7.Text + "',[Overtime]='" + this.textBox8.Text + "',[Normal 1]='" + this.textBox2.Text + "',[Overtime1]='" + this.textBox3.Text + "',[comments]='" + this.textBox4.Text + "',[Targets_(per hour)]='" + this.textBox5.Text + "'where  [Tasks Carried Out] ='" + this.comboBox1.SelectedText + "'; ";

    SqlConnection conDatabase = new SqlConnection(constring);
    SqlCommand cmdDataBase = new SqlCommand(Query, conDatabase);
    SqlDataReader myReader;

    try
    {
        conDatabase.Open();
        myReader = cmdDataBase.ExecuteReader();
        MessageBox.Show("Saved");

        while (myReader.Read())
        {
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

But my output comes : 01/01/1900 16:36 (I don't need the date in shift start and shift end  just only time). ANy help would be really appreciated.Please...

Comment: What data type are you using to store the time in the underlying Cau_reports table?

Comment: Also, a bit off topic, but I'd recommend you consider using SqlCommand & parameters

Comment: Yes, to parameterizing the query.  You'll save yourself all kinds of hassle over things like single quotes in the Comments field, or date/time formatting mismatches between the client machine and SQL, aside from the SQL Injection avoidance.

Answer (score 3):

Ensure you are using appropriate SQL Server [time](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677243.aspx) type for data column.

Comment: I have datetime type in sql and in my windows application form i have datetime pickers with format as time so, i have time from them.. CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),'" + this.SS.Text + "',108) = for shift start gives me this o/p   01/01/1900 16:36

Comment: @kiranv: if you have `DATETIME` in the SQL Server table, then you'll **always** have both a date and a time. You cannot avoid that. If you need **time only**, then use the appropriate datatype - `TIME(3)` or something like that!

Comment: Hi Mark, you are right.. but sql server managament studio does not have time datatype that's the first thing I was looking out for.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),'" + this.SS.Text + "',108)
```

108 return `hh:mm:ss`

Answer (score 0):

```
cast( '" + this.SS.Text + "' as time)
```

or

```
convert(char(5), '" + this.SS.Text + "', 108)
```

or

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),'" + this.SS.Text + "',108)
```

or

```
CONVERT(TIME,'" + this.SS.Text + "')
```

OR

Simply convert your datetimepicker value before using it in query as follows

`DateTimePicker1.Value.ToShortTimeString` or `DateTimePicker1.Value.tostring("HH:mm:ss")`

Comment: Have you tried changing datetimepicker value before using it in query. Please see my updates.

Comment: Can anyone know whats the problem  with my query.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server 2008 or later you can use the `TIME` datatype to store just a time.  If you are using an earlier version - your best choice is a `DATETIME` datatime, which will have a date component that you can ignore. Whatever *consumes* your data can always just display it as a time and disregard the date.

Another choice would be to store the time as a string, but if you ever need to do any comparisons or date math it may be more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: I cant see time datatype except(timestamp) which has nothing to do with my situation I use datetime where I am trying to ignore date and just display time but I am struggling to display it.I tried several ways but still no luck.